# getting custom post by tag

Tags: posts, tags

i getting custom post by tag - 
my cod :

```
$search_videos = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'videos',
    'tag' => $search_query
    );  

    $new_query = new WP_Query( $search_videos );
    $search_videos_posts = $new_query->posts;
```

but by this code just return post that have complet tag but i want return posts if a part of tag word entered , return posts

**EXAMPLE**
when search "akam" that return posts that have "akam" tag **BUT**
by search "aka" (a part of word) ,that return nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try this code as by using [`tag_slug__in`](https://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/), not `tag`.

```
$search_videos = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'videos',
    'tag_slug__in' => $search_query
    );  

    $new_query = new WP_Query( $search_videos );
    $search_videos_posts = $new_query->posts;
```

Comment: its work but just for all word not a part of word
example : when search tag "akam" return posts that have "akam" tag but, if search tag "aka" , return nothing